# Getting the error :"Needed Salesforce Engage Licence to view this"

Tags: configuration, pardot

**Actually downloaded the free Pardot package and asssigned one of my system administrator a salesforce engage licence**

[image]

The problem i am facing that there is no "sales cloud engage'' type license not displaying in Permission Set License Assignments.Why?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Do you have the necessary information from this [Engage License Assignment Troubleshooting](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000318278&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) article to help you troubleshoot the issue ?

Comment: yes gone through this article .the 2nd point permission set licence named'sales cloud engage' is not there

Comment: Do you see the Permission Set Assignment "Salesforce Engage" ?

Comment: Yes already assigned with user.

Comment: I suggest to log a case with Salesforce Support to further troubleshoot the issue

Comment: Already raised. Thanks Shamina & appreciate your intent towards solving the query.

Comment: hi @KAKUGARG, I am facing same issue. Is your issue resolved?